# Migrating Elastic bean stalk to another region but keeping the url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have an elastic beanstalk instance running in eu-west. I want to move it to us-east, but the problem is I have over a hundred lambdas pointing to its current url. Is there a way to retain the url for eu-west and simply have it route the new us-east url using say route 53?

Comment: Can you provide the format of the current URL?

Comment: Like below its xxxxxxx.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Elastic Beanstalk URLs have the region baked into them: `xxxxxxx.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`. So it cannot be "moved".

Also, the `elasticbeanstalk.com` domain is controlled by Amazon, so you cannot do anything using DNS/Route 53.

The closest you can do is to create an Elastic Beanstalk application which you host at the current location and it's sole purpose is to issue 301 redirects to the new location.

To avoid this issue in the future, use your own domain and point it to your EB application. If you need to move it, then you will be able to use DNS to move to the new location.

Comment: Okay thank you, but now my question is will the data coming back from the application in  us-east go straight to the requesting client, or will it first be sent to the redirect applciation and then routed from there? Im trying to get all amazon services into one region to lower cross region data out costs.

Comment: If you set it up with 301 redirects, then the data from us-east will return direct to the client.

Comment: Just a note, a 301 will only work with GET requests.  POST data will not be preserved on a 301 redirect. Not sure if that affects the OP implementation.

Comment: That's a good point. In my mind, I was thinking of a browser as the client, and they would GET from eu-west-1 and 301 to us-east-1, and from there would POST. However, the OP mentions Lambda, so they may be POSTing directly, in which case the 301 option won't work.